What was the first wish Dom asked Tess for?
At a pub, Tess informs Dom about a screen grab she found on a
traffic cam and stored in God's Eye. She mentions a hit in Rio
and asks if he has enemies there. Dom simply responds with "Reyes."
Tess recognizes the name as Hernan Reyes, who is deceased, but has
a son named Dante:

Dom: So you're gonna have to get me to Rio.
Tess: That's your second wish. You have one more.

I looked at the previous conversation between Dom and Tess, but I
couldn't find what Dom's first wish was that he asked Tess for.
What was the first wish Dom asked Tess for?
